# Hide checkbox from filter in devexpress gridView (xtragrid)

Tags: winforms, checkbox, grid, devexpress, xtragrid

I've a DevExpress XtraGrid control some columns and an unbounds column as boolean (so checkbox appears) for users to select the rows/items. I have applied filter as well. On column with checkBox in the filter row a checkbox appears at runtime. I don't want this checkbox to appear in filter row. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When a RepositoryItemCheckEdit assigned to the Column's ColumnEdit, a check box is also shown in the AutoFilterRow. To replace it with another editor, handle the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic.aspx) Event, check whether the e.RowHandle parameter equals the **GridControl.AutoFilterRowHandle** static property and provide a required RepositoryItem to the **e.RepositoryItem** property

Related link:
 1. [Assigning Editors to Individual Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument747)
 2. [Automatic Filtering Row](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument7097)